# Android app crashes with no proper error

Tags: android, sqlite

Im working on Android app which involves SQLite. I have a custom ListView.
when I click on an Item in the ListView it drills down and opens a new activity. And when I click back it comes to the ListView again but then when I scroll the ListView it gives some kind of weird error on the LogCat and crashes.

```
06-28 22:12:38.934: INFO/DEBUG(1017): *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***

06-28 22:12:38.934: INFO/DEBUG(1017): Build fingerprint: 

'generic/google_sdk/generic/:2.1/ERD79/22607:eng/test-keys'

06-28 22:12:38.934: INFO/DEBUG(1017): pid: 19157, tid: 19159  >>> 
com.xxxxxxxx.android <<<

06-28 22:12:38.944: INFO/DEBUG(1017): signal 11 (SIGSEGV), fault addr 00000004

06-28 22:12:38.944: INFO/DEBUG(1017):  r0 00000004  r1 40024258  r2 00000004  r3 4184bfd4

06-28 22:12:38.944: INFO/DEBUG(1017):  r4 00000000  r5 00000000  r6 42aadbde  r7 4184bfa8

06-28 22:12:38.944: INFO/DEBUG(1017):  r8 100ffcd8  r9 4184bfa0  10 4184bf8c  fp 00143cc0

06-28 22:12:38.954: INFO/DEBUG(1017):  ip ad361288  sp 100ffcc0  lr ad3287fb  pc afb04460  cpsr 00000010

06-28 22:12:39.365: INFO/DEBUG(1017):          #00  pc 00004460  /system/lib/libcutils.so

06-28 22:12:39.384: INFO/DEBUG(1017):          #01  pc 000287f8  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so

06-28 22:12:39.405: INFO/DEBUG(1017):          #02  pc 00046838  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so

06-28 22:12:39.405: INFO/DEBUG(1017):          #03  pc 0000f1f4  /system/lib/libdvm.so
06-28 22:12:39.415: INFO/DEBUG(1017):          #04  pc 00037f90  /system/lib/libdvm.so
06-28 22:12:39.435: INFO/DEBUG(1017):          #05  pc 00031612  /system/lib/libdvm.so
06-28 22:12:39.455: INFO/DEBUG(1017):          #06  pc 00013f58  /system/lib/libdvm.so
06-28 22:12:39.455: INFO/DEBUG(1017):          #07  pc 00019888  /system/lib/libdvm.so
06-28 22:12:39.465: INFO/DEBUG(1017):          #08  pc 00018d5c  /system/lib/libdvm.so
06-28 22:12:39.474: INFO/DEBUG(1017):          #09  pc 0004d6d0  /system/lib/libdvm.so
06-28 22:12:39.484: INFO/DEBUG(1017):          #10  pc 0004d702  /system/lib/libdvm.so
06-28 22:12:39.515: INFO/DEBUG(1017):          #11  pc 00043e40  /system/lib/libdvm.so
06-28 22:12:39.524: INFO/DEBUG(1017):          #12  pc 00043eda  /system/lib/libdvm.so
06-28 22:12:39.524: INFO/DEBUG(1017):          #13  pc 00044352  /system/lib/libdvm.so
06-28 22:12:39.534: INFO/DEBUG(1017):          #14  pc 00041b98  /system/lib/libdvm.so
06-28 22:12:39.554: INFO/DEBUG(1017):          #15  pc 00010000  /system/lib/libc.so
06-28 22:12:39.554: INFO/DEBUG(1017):          #16  pc 0000fad4  /system/lib/libc.so


06-28 22:12:39.575: INFO/DEBUG(1017): code around pc:
06-28 22:12:39.575: INFO/DEBUG(1017): afb04450 e8bd4010 e12fff1e e92d4010 e1a02000 
06-28 22:12:39.585: INFO/DEBUG(1017): afb04460 e5920000 e3e03a0f e28fe004 e2401001 
06-28 22:12:39.594: INFO/DEBUG(1017): afb04470 e243f03f 3afffff9 e2810001 e8bd4010 
06-28 22:12:39.604: INFO/DEBUG(1017): code around lr:
06-28 22:12:39.624: INFO/DEBUG(1017): ad3287e8 fffedb80 00005948 1c04b510 f7ef3004 
06-28 22:12:39.624: INFO/DEBUG(1017): ad3287f8 2801eeac 6060d104 68436820 47981c20 
06-28 22:12:39.624: INFO/DEBUG(1017): ad328808 46c0bd10 4c1ab5f0 1c05b083 1c1e447c 
06-28 22:12:39.624: INFO/DEBUG(1017): stack:
06-28 22:12:39.624: INFO/DEBUG(1017):     100ffc80  00002bb4  
06-28 22:12:39.624: INFO/DEBUG(1017):     100ffc84  000000dc  
06-28 22:12:39.624: INFO/DEBUG(1017):     100ffc88  100ffcd8  
06-28 22:12:39.633: INFO/DEBUG(1017):     100ffc8c  afe0b39b  /system/lib/libc.so
06-28 22:12:39.633: INFO/DEBUG(1017):     100ffc90  00000010  
06-28 22:12:39.633: INFO/DEBUG(1017):     100ffc94  afe3b9bc  
06-28 22:12:39.654: INFO/DEBUG(1017):     100ffc98  42a0f490  /data/dalvik-cache/system@framework@framework.jar@classes.dex


06-28 22:12:39.654: INFO/DEBUG(1017):     100ffc9c  42a0f490  /data/dalvik-cache/system@framework@framework.jar@classes.dex


06-28 22:12:39.654: INFO/DEBUG(1017):     100ffca0  00000001  
06-28 22:12:39.654: INFO/DEBUG(1017):     100ffca4  afe3baf0  
06-28 22:12:39.654: INFO/DEBUG(1017):     100ffca8  00000002  
06-28 22:12:39.654: INFO/DEBUG(1017):     100ffcac  418cd93c  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-LinearAlloc (deleted)


06-28 22:12:39.654: INFO/DEBUG(1017):     100ffcb0  100ffd20  
06-28 22:12:39.654: INFO/DEBUG(1017):     100ffcb4  000002a4  
06-28 22:12:39.654: INFO/DEBUG(1017):     100ffcb8  df002777  
06-28 22:12:39.674: INFO/DEBUG(1017):     100ffcbc  e3a070ad  
06-28 22:12:39.674: INFO/DEBUG(1017): #00 100ffcc0  00000000  
06-28 22:12:39.674: INFO/DEBUG(1017):     100ffcc4  ad3287fb  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so


06-28 22:12:39.674: INFO/DEBUG(1017): #01 100ffcc8  100ffcf8  
06-28 22:12:39.674: INFO/DEBUG(1017):     100ffccc  ad34683d  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so
```

Does anybody know what is this?
I would give more information. Let me know if you need something specific.

Comment: I assume you xxxx'd out your package name, does it show your package name, anywhere else in the stack trace? This is all DEBUG log we need ERROR

Comment: I have a similar issue in my app.  It showed up once I added AsyncTasks and Database accesses.  It happens in my Android 1.6 emulator but not on my 2.3 phone.

Comment: @Blundell: Yes I xxxxx'd out the project name. And it doesn't appear anywhere else in the log. This is what I have that appears everything the app crashes. No Errors nothing. It there a way I can debug this or find something on this.

Comment: Is this on an emulator? Have you tried a realdevice, or creating a new emulator?

Comment: @Blundell: Yes it is on emulator, Never tried on the device. But I guess I will create a new AVD and try on it. If nothing works then will have to try a device. Will keep you posted.  Thank for the help

Comment: @Blundell: I created a new emulator, for now its working fine. Didn't crash. Thanks a Lot for your help..

Answer (score 0):

This means the underlying C code is crashing which is very rare.
You could copy your project and remove as much code as possible to obtain a minimal code example that reproduces the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you xxxx'd out your package name, and it does not show your package name, anywhere else in the stack trace.

From what @Mibollama says it's the C code thats crashing so your emulator is screwed.

Delete the emulator and recreate a new one.

or

Test on a real device.

Be careful with your emulators if you have "load from image" and "save to image" ticked in the emulator config, once you have an error you will always have it unless you wipe the image.

In your case it looks like the emulators' code itself got into a muddle, so creating a whole new 1 is the best idea.